# Como hacer un TOP de productos

Tags: c++, dev-c++

lo que necesito saber es como hacer un top de tres productos más vendidos. Así a simple vista parece sencillo, pero no lo es (por lo menos para mí vaya).

La manera de la que lo he hecho es la siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nL; i++)
    {
        
        if(vec[i].vendidos > tVendido){
            if(vec[i].vendidos > sVendido){
                if(vec[i].vendidos > pVendido){
                    v[0] = vec[i];
                    pVendido = vec[i].vendidos;
                }
                v[1] = vec[i];
                sVendido = vec[i].vendidos;
            }
            v[2] = vec[i];
        }
    }
```

Pero el problema que surge con esta manera es que dependiendo del orden de los productos puede salir bien o no. Alguna otra idea de como hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Qué es `tVendido`, `sVendido` y `pVendido`?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y da más detalles

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que tu colección de productos no está ordenada, podrías ordenarla y quedarte con los tres primeros valores:

```
struct producto
{
    int id, vendidos;
};

int main()
{
    producto p[]
    {
        0, 0,
        1, 1,
        2, 2,
        3, 32,
        4, 45,
        5, 9,
        6, 8,
        7, 7,
        8, 6,
        9, 55,
        10, 10,
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(p), std::end(p),
        // Orden de mayor a menor
        [](const producto &a, const producto &b) { return a.vendidos > b.vendidos; });

    for (int top = 0; top != 3; ++top)
        std::cout
            << "Top " << top << ' '
            << p[top].id << '\t'
            << p[top].vendidos << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLbsIwEDzHXzGlUkmECwlvCPALvfRGOZg4pZaIHTlOpQrx7XRt8ZA4zezseHdsF3X9XhyFPlwur0oXx1aWWCnTOFuKasMemjgejFXuh0RG3bZwqK2RhIadWKS0g5Icv6WWSpomZ@ecMa9WQuk48Z6bH/V2xyISopQj5YQZR@ZxyDH0OOIYBTLmGE88mXAsPE455h5nHDOPc46pxwXHJBgzmpn5oX5/1Di5XDbGujiwfXmgMHXCEUrK6gs6NRjgw8pSg65aiT9jIVCV2ljqbXdxYXTzuC/eBMeztE9wgi1dazVE//YM2GB/L3KcEx/qm8bH/mmcqbFGmgfyssYoR69HPKGtIWBhWkc8Wq3Q@SRPB8S8maCL7rVVb0na9ZUM8pd70u9ZQld3fYRr0JS@6XL5Bw)</kbd>.

Si no puedes modificar tu colección de productos, ordena los índices:

```
producto p[]
{
    0, 0,
    1, 1,
    2, 2,
    3, 32,
    4, 45,
    5, 9,
    6, 8,
    7, 7,
    8, 6,
    9, 55,
    10, 10,
};
int indices[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

std::sort(std::begin(indices), std::end(indices),
    // Orden de mayor a menor
    [&p](int a, int b) { return p[a].vendidos > p[b].vendidos; });

for (int top = 0; top != 3; ++top)
    std::cout
        << "Top " << top << ' '
        << p[indices[top]].id << '\t'
        << p[indices[top]].vendidos << '\n';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLbsIwEDzHX7GlUiFiSxNCeAX4hV56S3MwsUstETtyTKUK8e3p2oVy6mnGs5Pd2U3dts/1ketD3z8qXR9PQsJGmc5ZyZsdu2v8eDBWuU8SGVVPtYPWGkFo2JlFSjtQAuFLaqGE6Qp2KRjzasOVHsXec/NDW1YsIiFKEBIkTBFSj1OEqccMIQtkhjDLPckRVh7nCEuPC4SFxyXC3OMKIQ/GlHqmvinN/01FgWrZldU5wRSnmOEMc5zjApe4wjTxOaPOifW6M9aNAtvLA4W@fhkjBJE2u0s06eUFXq2QGug8Df82Fjg0UhtLtfKprUZ@OkfwsI/hDFa6k9W0Pa8mtzvBjt77@7uAS@wDfVC70MCZFraQFIE8bCErYDwmHtOUEKs2J0c82mxg8EaeARDzZoIhDK@ltrzdgUpVNVEi1N/df4a/gMGmhz7UdYGEfm7f/wA)</kbd>.